# program installation permission denied chimera

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

[image: installation problem]
I am not able to install any program i am getting permission denied bash

Comment: try sudo or chmod a+x *.bin

Comment: i tried sudo not working , what is a+x , is a+X are file ?

Comment: @sriramraghavan - a means all, i.e., user, group, others and x means executable, i.e., you are giving all users an executable permission to execute the file.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the commands and the error you get here, and use code formatting.

Comment: sudo su, or sudo -i

Answer (score 1):

Your script needs executable permissions. To do so type the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads && chmod a+x chimera-1.10.2-linux_x86_64.bin
```

Then to run it type:

```
./chimera-1.10.2-linux_x86_64.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it executable by the `chmod` command, so type :

```
chmod +x chimera-1.10.2-linux_x86_64.bin
```

Then you need to launch it it as a root by typing

```
sudo ./chimera-1.10.2-linux_x86_64.bin
```

For more information check [the official documentation](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/data/downloads/1.10.2/linux_x86_64.html).